# Jquery delay for 5 sec

Tags: jquery

I have in jquery I want to delay 5 sec to the function

```
$(target).slideDown("slow","linear", function(){ 
                    $(target).addClass('section-active');
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
                    }, 1000, 'easeInOutExpo', function() {
                        isScrolling = false;
                        startNano.go();
                    });
                });
```

How can I achieve

Answer (score 1):

Built in javascript setTimeout. Also you could use `.delay` method for jquery 1.4.0+.
[check it out here](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

setTimeout method would look like something like this:

```
    $(target).slideDown("slow","linear", function(){ 
      setTimeout(function(){
      $(target).addClass('section-active');
      $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
      }, 1000, 'easeInOutExpo', function() {
         isScrolling = false;
         startNano.go();
    });
  }, 5000); //5000 = 5 seconds
});
```

The `.delay` method would be the following:

```
$(target).slideDown("slow","linear", function(){ 
          $(target).addClass('section-active');
          $('html, body').delay(5000).animate({
             scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
          }, 1000, 'easeInOutExpo', function() {
             isScrolling = false;
             startNano.go();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimeout()`. It calls a function or evaluates an expression after a specified number of milliseconds

```
$(target).slideDown("slow","linear", function(){ 
  setTimeout(function(){
    $(target).addClass('section-active');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
    }, 1000, 'easeInOutExpo', function() {
        isScrolling = false;
        startNano.go();
    });
  }, 5000); //5 seconds
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use `setTimeout()` function

```
    setTimeout(function(){
       $(target).slideDown("slow","linear", function(){ 
       $(target).addClass('section-active');
       $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
         }, 1000, 'easeInOutExpo', function() {
          isScrolling = false;
          startNano.go();
        });
      });
     },5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can chain a delay in-between animation or callback events using .delay(5000) which is a jQuery function.

However, as (if I've understood correctly) you want it to wait before it does anything, we can work around that by putting a stop() before we ask it to delay then chain off the end of that.

```
$('html, body').stop(true, true).delay(5000).animate(...)
```